# Does always exist a prime number between $n(n+1)$ and $(n+1)(n+2)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n$ is positive integer number, does always exist a prime number between $n(n+1)$ and $(n+1)(n+2)$?

Comment: The difference between $n(n+1)$ and $(n+1)(n+2)$ is $2(n+1) = 2n + 2$. Also, $n(n+1)$ is $n$ larger than $n^2$, plus $(n+1)(n+2) = n^2 + 3n + 2$ is $n + 1$ larger than $(n+1)^2$. Thus, what you're asking is very similar to [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) and, as such, I suspect it's also currently unknown.

Comment: It is suspected, but far from being proven.

Comment: It is likely, that, letting $\Delta_{n}:=(n+1)(n+2)-n(n+1)$, one should have $\pi((n+1)(n+2))-\pi(n(n+1))>(1+o(1))\frac{\pi(\Delta_{n})^{2}}{\Delta_{n}}$.

Comment: See also the marginally stronger conjecture of Oppermann: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 10):

It is widely believed that there indeed exists a prime between $n(n+1)$ and $(n+1)(n+2)$ for every integer $n\geq 1$.  This appears to be beyond the scope of existing methods, however.  Even the easier problem of find a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$ for all integers $n\geq 1$ appears to be beyond the scope of existing methods.  Dudek recently [proved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4233) that there exists a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$ for all $n\geq \exp\exp(33.217)$.  Such an explicit threshold is not yet known to exist for primes between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$; your proposed problem has a similar predicament.

Comment: We don't know that a threshold exists for the OP's question. That is, currently we cannot exclude the possibility that infinitely many counterexamples $n$ exist.

Comment: @GHfromMO So the same would hold for Legendre's problem?  I didn't realize that so little was known!

Comment: Yes, same for Legendre's problem. We don't even know that, for large $x$, there always exists a prime in $[x,x+x^{0.501}]$, which is much weaker than either of the two conjectures.

Comment: @GHfromMO Good point...I should've caught that.  I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best result is due to Baker, Harman, and Pintz. They proved the existence of a prime in $[x,x+x^{0.525}]$ for sufficiently large $x$.